# Getting the value of a Map in Struts2 JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, dictionary, struts2

I am loading a map of values into ServletContext during start of the application/server

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> cfsUfsMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
//some operations
application.setAttribute("UDM_UFS_CFS_MAP", cfsUfsMap); //application = ServletContext
```

I need to use this map directly in JSP page, for which I have done this

```
<s:set name="udm_cfs_ufs_map" value="#application.UDM_UFS_CFS_MAP" />
<table class="first" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" id="sups_assignedservices_info_table">
<tr>
    <th width="30%">Assigned service name </th>
    <th width="15%">CFS Code </th>
    <th width="15%">Status </th>
    <th width="20%">Date </th>
    <th width="20%">UDM </th>
</tr>
<s:iterator value="#sups_services.services">
    <s:set name="ufs_list" value="#udm_cfs_ufs_map.['top.code']" /> 
    <tr>                
        <td class="light"><s:property value="top.name"/> </td>
        <td class="light"><s:property value="top.code"/> </td>
        <td class="light"><s:property value="top.status"/> </td>
        <td class="light"><s:property value="top.date"/> </td>  
        <td class="light"><s:property value="#udm_cfs_ufs_map.size()" /> - <s:property value="#ufs_list.size()" /></td>
    </tr>   
</s:iterator>
```

As you see, I am trying to get the values (List) from map using key which's top.code 
However I am getting original map size but not the list size based on key.

Any idea what's missing/going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done.

I solved it myself. I am posting my mistakes and the correct solution. SO down the line it might be useful to someone

to access servletContext attributes

```
<s:set name="udm_cfs_ufs_map" value="#application.UDM_UFS_CFS_MAP" />
```

for fetching the content from the map based on key

```
<s:iterator value="#sups_services.services">
<s:set name="ufs_list" value="#udm_cfs_ufs_map[top.code]" />
<tr>
    <td class="light"><s:property value="top.name" /></td>
    <td class="light"><s:property value="top.code" /></td>
    <td class="light"><s:property value="top.status" />
    </td>
    <td class="light"><s:property value="top.date" /></td>
    <td class="light"><s:iterator value="ufs_list">
            <s:property />
            <br />
        </s:iterator></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I'd rather see a `var` in the iterator tag; using `top`, while it works, is rather sensitive to any changes that might affect what's actually on top of the stack.